# Filter based on Unique Values that only match certain criteria

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

This may be beyond my skill level in Google Sheets, and it's certainly straining my brain to think through, but I have two columns out a large spreadsheet (30000 lines or so) that I need to find matches between unique values on one list, and non-unique but specific values ONLY on another list.  That is, I would need the following list to return only the values on the left that had a 3 in the right column *every time that value appears on the left*, not just for a specific instance.

| "Unique" Identifier (can repeat) | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |

I have the following formula from another couple answers mocked up, but it doesn't get me all the way there:=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,B2:B>0))

How can I get it to exclude the ones that have, for instance, both a 2 and a 3 in the right column for the same value in the left column?

Edit: To put it in more real terms (I was trying to keep it abstract so I could understand the basics), I have a Catalog ID and a Condition for items, and need to find all Catalog IDs that only have Good copies, not any Very Good copies.  This link should show what I want to achieve:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSjenkDS2Mk3t4kTcDoJqSc8AV6ONu4Q17K1HPaIUdJkb7dhdnbAt-CzUxGO3ZoJISNpGajUtFTGz8c/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSjenkDS2Mk3t4kTcDoJqSc8AV6ONu4Q17K1HPaIUdJkb7dhdnbAt-CzUxGO3ZoJISNpGajUtFTGz8c/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

Comment: Hopefully that link works.  Not sure how else to do it.  I included in that a description of what I want to accomplish, with a more exact example of the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to return only the values on the left that had a 3 in the right column every time

try:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A; B:B=3))
```

---

### update 1:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet1!A:A; Sheet1!B:B="Good"))
```

### update 2:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet1!A:A, Sheet1!B:B="Good", 
 NOT(COUNTIF(FILTER(Sheet1!A:A, Sheet1!B:B<>"Good"), Sheet1!A:A))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't quite do what I want, and I realized I may not have been precise enough in my statement.  That returned, in this example, 2 and 5, which both have a 3 in some instances and a 2 in others.  I would have actually wanted it to return nothing if I input a 3.  Rather, I would want to input 2 (and I tested this) and get back just 1,3,4, and 6, since those never have a 3 in the right column, any time they show up.  Instead it returned every number, which isn't what I want. Does that explain what I'm looking for better?

Comment: Thanks, but when I use that, it still (in the example spreadsheet I provided) returns 24689, which also has a "Very Good" row.  I want it to exclude that since it has both options showing.  That's the really tricky part of what I'm trying to accomplish, I know.

Comment: @jondesu answer updated

Comment: Thanks, you got it!  Now one last ask, if I wanted to expand that to include additional conditions that were included in the answer, like Acceptable, how would I do that?  I tried the following, but it didn't like it (gave me a formula parse error): =UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet1!A:A, OR(Sheet1!B:B="Good", Sheet1!B:B="Acceptable")
 NOT(COUNTIF(FILTER(Sheet1!A:A, OR(Sheet1!B:B<>"Good", Sheet1!B:B="Acceptable"), Sheet1!A:A))))

Comment: @jondesu OR and AND are not supported under FILTER. use regex: REGEXMATCH(Sheet1!B:B, "Good|Acceptable")